# SwiftUI Animation + URLSession

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm not quite sure what's happening here, hopefully somebody can assist.

I've reproduced a tiny example which I've included below.

I have an App with a single view (shown below).

When a user taps a text view, it should animate the movement of a rectangle and at the same time, perform a http request.

My understanding is that URLSession will use another thread and therefore should not block the main thread or any UI performance. However, the first time I tap a text view, the animation stutters / jitters, but every other time I tap a text view, it works smoothly.

I've tried a range of different approaches including withAnimation, dispatch queues, combine and so on. Always the same outcome.

Any ideas?

```
struct Demo: View {
    
    @State var position: CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                .offset(x: position * 50)
                .animation(.easeInOut, value: position)
            HStack {
                ForEach(1..<10) { num in
                    Text("\(num) Button")
                        .onTapGesture {
                            position = CGFloat(num)
                            
                            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
                            let task = session.dataTask(with: URL(string: "https://mywebsite")!) { data, response, error in
                                print(data ?? "no data")
                            }
                            
                            task.resume()
                            
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Does the issue persist if you remove networking code? 2) Did you try to initialise session outside of tap handler, as a Demo instance property, and only create task in tap handler?

Comment: If I remove the networking code, and just have the simple animation on tap - all works fine. It's as soon as the networking code is added. I've just tried to create session as a property of the demo struct and I see the same issue. Delayed / stuttering UI on first tap, with all further taps being smooth.

Comment: "My understanding is that URLSession will use another thread and therefore should not block the main thread" - not when it's waiting for data. But all the synchronous code, including expensive `URLSession` creation, as well as `session.dataTask` creation, which can be expensive, will run on main thread. So consider moving at least `URLSession` creation out of this code (in general there's rarely a reason to have more than 1 session overall).